# Rails - How to convert path to URL in views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, path, view-helpers

As title, in my mailer views, I need a helper to convert pathes to URLs:

```
= link_to "Click Me", convert_to_urlh#with_hash")
```

I expected `convert_to_url("/some_path#with_hash")` to generate `http://localhost:3000/some_path#with_hash`.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? (https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/actionpack/4.1.6/symbols/ActionDispatch::Routing::UrlFor/url_for?d=137394105&n=0#tab=Docs&d=137394105&n=0) I am not sure `url_for` works like that. Just do `link_to "Click Me", "/some_path#with_hash"` and you are done.

Comment: Hardcoding urls in links is usually bad practice. What action do you want to route to?

Comment: I need URL in emails. I shouldn't use `url_for` in the question. I am looking for a helper for this purpose.

Comment: So what controller/action do you want to route to?

Comment: "users" controller and "show" action.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `url_for` here as the `link_to` method already calls it with the second argument. Instead try this:

```
link_to 'Click Me', '/some_path#with_hash'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get URL in ActionMailer, then you need to specify `:host`. You can use plain `url_for`, `polymorphic_url` or generated named routes methods.

For example:

```
<%= link_to 'Click me', user_url(@user, host: "example.com") %>
```

In views and controllers Rails substitute `:host` automagically

More information:

- about AM: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html
- about `url_for`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html
- about `polymorphic_url`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes